# Python with VS2012

Tags: python-3.x, nltk

I just start with NLTK ,when i try to instal NLTK with python in the VS2012 IDE
first i run:

```
import nltk
nltk.download()
```

It runs correctly.Then I try:

```
from nltk.book import *
```

It gives me:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\Extensio
ns\Microsoft\Python Tools for Visual Studio\2.1\visualstudio_py_util.py", line 1
06, in exec_file
    exec_code(code, file, global_variables)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\Extensio
ns\Microsoft\Python Tools for Visual Studio\2.1\visualstudio_py_util.py", line 8
1, in exec_code
    code_obj = compile(code, file, 'exec')
  File "C:\Users\Toshiba\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Helloworld\Hellow
orld\module2.py", line 2
    NLTK_DADA ="E:\NLtk\nltk_data"
              ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in positio
n 2-3: malformed \N character escape
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error itself says it all:

```
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in positio
n 2-3: malformed \N character escape
```

The path you are using is badly formatted for python. You need to escape the `\` character itself, otherwise python thinks you are escaping the character that follows the `\`.

Proper string formatting:

```
NLTK_DADA = "E:\\NLtk\\nltk_data"
```

Another way is to tell python that the string is a *raw string* by prefixing it with `r`:

```
NLTK_DADA = r"E:\NLtk\nltk_data"
```

See [string literals](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals) in python.